# Change the helper.php path for com_ajax

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, com-ajax

I'm trying to use Joomla's com_ajax for my module by using this url : `index.php?option=com_ajax&module=MODNAME&method=MODMETHOD&format=json`

However my helper.php file is located under folder `modules/mod_modname/helper/` while joomla's com_ajax is always trying to find the helper file in `modules/mod_modname/` so it returned error :

```
> {"success":false,"message":"The file at mod_modname\/helper.php does
> not exist.","messages":null,"data":null}
```

How can I tell the com_ajax the path of my helper.php file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

The component looks for the helper like so:

```
$helperFile = JPATH_BASE . '/modules/mod_' . $module . '/helper.php';
```

where `$module` is the name of your module.

You will have to move the `helper.php` to `modules/mod_modname`

Comment: So how about with joomla 4's modules those are commonly placed the helper.php under `/modules/mod_modname/src/Helper`. Is it a bug or issue?

Comment: I've reported this issue anyway https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/32136